# basic / efficient Prototypical inheritance in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

So I currently have the following code snippet. I am trying to create a `Cylon` class, which contains a model property and a prototype `attack()` method. I am creating a `HumanSkin` class, which inherits from the `Cylon`, and also adds its own prototype `infiltrate()` method.

```
function Cylon(model){
  this.model = model;
}

Cylon.prototype.attack = function(){
    return("Destroy all humans!");
}

function HumanSkin(){}
HumanSkin.prototype = new Cylon();
HumanSkin.prototype.infiltrate = function(){
  return("Infiltrate the colonies");
}

cylon = new Cylon("raider");
caprica = new HumanSkin(6);
```

My issue is this -- why is `console.log(caprica.model);` returning `Undefined`? How can I easily get full inheritance (preferably with encapsulation) in JS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you say,

```
HumanSkin.prototype = new Cylon();
```

you are creating a new object of `Cylon`, with an empty model (`undefined`). So, inheriting from `Cylon`, could be improved like this

```
HumanSkin.prototype = Object.create(Cylon.prototype);
```

Note that, When you inherit with prototypal inheritance, whatever is in the `prototype` of the parent will be available to the child. But `model` is in the `Cylon`'s constructor. Normally, this can be solved like this

```
function HumanSkin(model) {
    Cylon.call(this, model);
}
```

Now, whenever you construct a new `HumanSkin` object, internally `Cylon` function will be invoked with the current object (`this`) and the `model` will be passed as an argument to that. So, `Cylon` will be initializing the `model` in the current object.

Comment: Hi -- great answer, thanks! Is there a better way to encapsulate prototypal classes? I don't like how the constructor method and then the prototype code are all separated out.

Comment: @Prefix Well, that is actually the best way. Because, whatever is in the constructor will be created everytime you create an object. So, it is better to put the functions in the prototype and all the instance specific data in the constructor.

Comment: @Prefix You might also want to read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures#Performance_considerations)

Comment: what is the advantage of `Cylon.call(this,model);` over `this.__proto__= new Cylon(model);`?

Comment: @Prefix Two things. 1) [`__proto__` is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto), 2) You are creating a new object and sticking that as the prototype. You are mixing instance and the prototypes.

Comment: Great, thank you -- I definitely don't want to do that. Trying to figure out the most computationally efficient way to do classes/inheritance in JS is tricky!